# Command to list partition type codes in deb and rpm distributions for MBR and GPT

Tags: partition, command, gpt, mbr, lsblk

Is there any command to **list all partition type codes recognizable** by currently installed
distribution (In my case Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS)

I know the following website exists [**Andries E. Brouwer 1995-2002 - homepages.cwi.nl**](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/disk/partition_types-1.html)
yet there should be any command inbuilt in the linux console.

I know that **cgdisk** shows all partition codes while creating new partition

[image: The screenshot1 is provided from my own system]

[image: The screenshot2 is provided from my own system]

> *Provided screenshots from my own system while formatting a pendrive creating bootable Ubuntu 20.04 lts usb*

Yet again my question is, Is there any command that can show all recognizable partition
 
type codes for MBR and GPT for the current distribution or if there is any
man pages that has reference?

Or may be this is different for the different tools?

Example of MBR partition types codes [thestarman.pcministry.com](https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/PartTypes.htm)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by “supported”? Linux distributions don’t care about partition types.

Comment: Also DEB and RPM distros contain pretty much the same utilities. There's zero difference in fdisk/sfdisk/gdisk/cfdisk/etc. between e.g. Fedora and Ubuntu.

Comment: Actually there is minor difference between fdisk/sfdisk/gdisk/cfdisk some doesn't show the list of partition types like the cgdisk from what I know. The thing is that I can't get list of all partition codes like MS partition is 0700 or 8300 for Linux.
I can check the partition types and codes list in the mentioned website https://homepages.cwi.nl/~aeb/linux/disk/partition_types-1.html
but for example if I want to list all /dev/sdb or sda or sd whatever without the loop devices in recent distributions like Ubuntu 18.04LTS or newer, I have those multiple loop devices.

Comment: So in order to list all /dev/sd* I found that lsblk -e7 will remove all loop devices from the output, but I should know that 7 stands for the loop device types.
Now I'm interested in a way of listing all partition identifiers/types with the corresponding codes for those.

Comment: Just try lsblk and lsblk -e7 for yourself and you will get the point of my question if you also have all those loop devices in your distribution.

Comment: Try: `lsblk -e 7 -o name,size,type,fstype,mountpoint,parttype` & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table

Comment: lsblk -e 7 -o name,size,type,fstype,mountpoint,parttype
I like this one, it shows the partition code, I also checked the wiki for Partition Tables,
what I still don't understand is if there is any declared list with partition codes for partition tables recognized by Linux inbuilt tools or man pages.
It seems it's tool bond, system bond and partition table bond somehow so there might not be any universal list with partition codes for MBR and GPT neither a command that will list those.

Comment: OK clearly there is no command for this function. Apparently the partition codes are bios, partition table, system and tool dependent. So it looks like the only way to know the partition code is reading the specific manual for the specific tool, system, initialization system (systemd / OpenRC/ System V / init / etc) , partition table and bios.

Comment: There is great variance in relevance for these codes. Most of them are either obsolete or very specialized. A better approach is to ask the question "what is this partition for?", and select a partition code based on that. The meaning of the codes has also changed over time from specifying the filesystem type to telling what role the partition has (root fs, etc). MBR is slowly but steadily losing significance, and GPT does not actually store short codes, only UUIDs, and the utilities fake the short codes based on the UUIDs.

Comment: I recommend reading the document https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/DiscoverablePartitionsSpec/ This document has more relevance today for determining the use of partitions than the partition type has ever had in determining the type of the filesystem contained in the partition. Like Stephen Kitt said, Linux has never cared about partition types (well, at least for determining the filesystem type).

Comment: Thanks now it's getting clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally I found that it's mainly dependent of the filesystem and the volume
identification hex code is/should be present in the filesystem documentation
as seen below for NTFS and EXT4

> ***Conclusion***: There is not specific command or tool only for listing partitions hex code besides the function of cgdisk, gdisk, cfdisk, fdisk, etc while creating the partition.

> **gdisk** - list partition hex code previous to creation
> **cgdisk, cfdisk and fdisk** - list partition hex code during creation only

**NTFS Partition** $VOLUME_INFORMATION 0x70 Attribute
http://dubeyko.com/development/FileSystems/NTFS/ntfsdoc.pdf

**EXT4 Partition** Identifier for MBR (right column)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4

This post partially answers the question also
[Why does parted need a filesystem type when creating a partition, and how does its action differ from a utility like mkfs.ext4?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551030/why-does-parted-need-a-filesystem-type-when-creating-a-partition-and-how-does-i)

> "A partition can have a type. The partition type is a hint as in "this partition is designated to serve a certain function". Many partition types are associated with certain file-systems, though the **association is not always strict or unambiguous**. You can expect a partition of type 0x07 to have a Microsoft compatible file-system (e.g. FAT, NTFS or exFAT) and 0x83 to have a native Linux file-system (e.g. ext2/3/4)."

So apparently the code is not always strictly associated as shown in the previous answer.
For example **EXT4 83h** Any native Linux file system (see **93h**, corresponds with **43h**)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type#PID_83h

Or **Solaris ZFS** for example as seen in **BFh** and **82h** sections
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type#PID_BFh
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type#PID_82h

**Additional examples** information gathered during the research
**ZFS** Attributes BF01 BF07 EF02
**BF01** special hex type code **Solaris Partition**
**BF07** special hex type code **Solaris Reserved 1**
**EF02** special hex type code **BIOS Boot Partition**
https://www.it-swarm-es.tech/es/gdisk/codigos-hex-de-gdisk/961390299/