# Why does Parted mkpart ask for file system type, if I can later format with another file system?

Tags: filesystems, partition, parted, partition-table, mkfs

## What I Did

1. I attach an HDD, `lsblk -S` shows this drive as *sdc*
2. I use `sudo parted /dev/sdc/` to start parted against *sdc*
3. I create a partition table as: `mklabel gpt`
4. I make a partition: `mkpart my-cool-partition` and,
5. select **ext2** as my file type

## According to man, this actually:

> Creates a new partition, *without* creating a new file system on that partition

> You may specify a file system type, to set the appropriate partition code in the partition table for the new partition

Therefore, I understand that Parted kindly "provisioned" or "optimized" (I hope that's the correct mindset) for me to later format the drive with **ext2**, for my above example.

## However...

6. then I use `sudo mkfs.ntfs` to format with **NTFS** instead of **ext2**. The result is: `mkntfs completed successfully. Have a nice day`

I don't understand how `mkpart` is necessary at all. I will not lie to Parted in real life, but if I did, will there be problems?

*Environment: Debian, XFCE, xfce4-terminal, Bash*

Comment: Does https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551030/why-does-parted-need-a-filesystem-type-when-creating-a-partition-and-how-does-i/551033#551033 answer your question?

Comment: Yes, that awesome post answered most of my doubt. Before I closed this post as a duplicate, I received yet another great answer, so I accepted the answer instead of closing this question. I also up-voted [that answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551030/why-does-parted-need-a-filesystem-type-when-creating-a-partition-and-how-does-i/551033#551033).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on where you're going to use that disk: there might be problems - Linux doesn't care, but other OS'es/appliances might.

Years ago I had a box for recording TV that needed an external disk to save the recordings to. The documentation for the box said that it supported using NTFS and VFAT, but the box' own software only supported making NTFS, and as NTFS wasn't well-supported on Linux (it might have been read-only or something, and I wanted to be able to use it from Linux) in those days. So I attached the disk to my linux, and made a VFAT filesystem on it. When I moved it back to the box, it could see the disk but not use it (it might have tried, but failed very quickly). I had a hard time figuring out what was wrong, until I for some reason got to think about partition types - and quite right: the partition was marked to contain an NTFS filesystem, but contained a VFAT filesystem (because I hadn't cared about the partition type when, as soon as I had changed the partition type, the box had no problems using the disk.